# How to place body at center of page regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css

How do I ensure that my content is always at the center of the page? I set the min and max width and height to a fixed number of pixels and placed the body at margin-left: 32%. But when I change the browser size the body shifts away from the center. Is there another to make sure everything stays at the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set margin-left to a percent on the body tag, it'll only be center for a specific screen size. Instead in your css file set:

```
body{margin:0 auto;}
```

### [Here’s an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3tXXp/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note you should use the **margin: 0 auto** only on the actual container of your content. Usually it is used like:

```
body{
background: red;
}

.container{
background: green;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

For this the html in the body would look like

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    ****your content****
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice point. Do you know if this conflicts with Bootstrap placement?

Answer (score 1):

Applying margin: 0 auto on a wrapper is the most common way of centering elements. To be sure your content is always at the center of your screen, wrap it in a container div, specify a width(for RWD percentages are the most usefull). With margin: 0 auto you almost can't go wrong, but there is another way that also works really well.

You can use position: relative; and css3's translate to center your content. If you use percentages for the positioning and the translate, it never can go wrong.

Basic code:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    The content
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS(written in Sass):

```
div#wrapper
  width: 75% // can be whatever you use
  position: relative
  left: 50%
  +translateX(-50%)
```

+translateX() is a Compass mixin for

```
 transform: translateX();
```

I've made a pen with an example: http://codepen.io/stijneversdijk/pen/hlICH

Good luck!